# Why aren't method parameters contravariant in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript you are allowed to have a covariant method parameter in the derived class.
It looks like a blatant violation of LSP.
What is an intention for this piece of the language design, is it deliberate or a design limitation?

```js
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number;
}

class Base {
    public foo(arg0: A): B { 
        return { a: 0, b: 42 };
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public foo(arg0: B): B { // covariant parameter is allowed, not OK
        return { a: +arg0.a.toPrecision(2), b: +arg0.b.toPrecision(2) }; // runtime error, b is undefined, although should have been required
    }
}

let b: Base = new Derived(); // Assign a sub class to a base class should always be ok 
b.foo({ a: 10}); // no need to pass in b, right ?
```

Comment: B extends A, and thats why it is ok. If I understand the question correctly

Comment: @John That is why the compiler allows it, but OP is right, it does break liskov:

Comment: @John https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2gG4sBfLLUSWRFAIWQgA9IQATAM5pMOPBSKlKNeowQAbOIOHslKbHmQAHEhXnAEyGAHtjACjhQA5gAYiqAJRFOGZGM24oEMCSghM+EQ2ADTIEsgALABMyHS0mgwMWApKwgAi0MAAbhD8XLwQAipqopo6egZGphbWdsjsTvUBAPTNyAjGWZbAcODalnBk3tDIwMJw8vLGAO65oSDGYMgA8gDS7h5ePn4BhMgA1Ja2AHRwx2DGAApeCGPAxiBmUQ6h4Ye1xxTnVzd3D08OWLUZCtZBQEjgYBDLhQKDGKCvUbCCH8CAwUBzfDyMAAC2MJCsOOQgjxJHkeRxcByYQghTBEBIwC8-A2iUY8m8YWcJQAvMQINNkBkoNlcmYHMDQahlMArP44MTdO1FMpkBd8GESilVST8fx5FjpnAAJ7CKjIYwAazcXxM5lcewAjDY6BKQW0FvzcmrjP1VaAwqERYSlgB+IA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods parameters behave bivariantly in typescript. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717) to make them behave contravariantly, but since it's been open since 2016, it probably isn't a priority.

There is an option (`strictFunctionTypes`) to make parameters of function signatures not originating in methods behave contravariantly but methods are explicitly exempt from the stricter checks. From the [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) introducing this stricter mode for functions we get an idea of the reasoning behind the method exemption:

> Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode).

Comment: You may want to add this to your post: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717

Comment: @kabanus that is a nice proposal, too bad it's been open since 2016. Probably will not see the light of say any time soon 

Comment: The proposal was closed as completed in March 2022, however, from what I understand the PR that closed it does not actually deal with this problem. So I guess the conclusion is still that this is just how it is and (especially now) we cannot expect it to change in the foreseeable future?